# SQl update from two tables to another based on an ID match

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

I have a database with 3 tables `users` `contest` and  `memberBets`. I want to update `memberBets` using `users` and `contest`. Below is the relevant data from each table and the code I have tried. I am looking for advise on whether the approach I am taking is correct or not.

`users`:

```
id      fname     lname     email             password
1       John      Doe       test@test.com     test
```

`contest`:

```
contestID      team1    odds_team1     
1              test     5.0
```

`memberBets`:

```
id      contestID   usersID    betName   betAmount   betOdds
```

I am looking to put contestID in contest into ContestID in memberBets, id from users into usersID in memberBets team1 from contest into betName from memberBets, betAmount will be from the modal I am using and finally odds_team1 from contest into betOdds from memberBets.

```
if(isset($_POST['placeBetTeam1'])){
              $Team1BetAmount = $_POST['Team1BetAmount'];
              echo $Team1BetAmount;
              $sql =    "UPDATE memberBets 
                        SET contestID= contest.contestID,
                            usersID= users.id,
                            betName= contest.team1,
                            betAmount= $Team1BetAmount,
                            betOdds= contest.odds_team1
                        FROM users, contest
                        WHERE users.id= '".escape($_SESSION['id'])."'";

                //echo $sql;
              if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
               redirect("index.php");
             } else {
               echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
              }

              $conn->close();
```

This is what I am trying and it doesn't seem to be working. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: See the syntax for UPDATE

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: You can not use FROM in that query.
Try to divide it into 3 queries:
1. Get needed value from contest and set it to variable. (SELECT query)
2. Get needed value from users and set it to variable (SELECT query)
3. Perform UPDATE query in which you include these 2 variables.

I would also recommend to use transaction for that so you would be sure.

Another way, more complex is to use nested queries to get values from other tables.

Comment: @GrzegorzLasak A one-query approach seems more sensible

Comment: @Strawberry That is why I mentioned nested query technique so post's author can choose best way ;)

Comment: here what is the relation between users and contest tables

Comment: Also, consider whether you really want to store derived data.

Comment: @stickybit I am aware of SQL Injection this is purely for personal use thank you for your comment however!

Comment: @GrzegorzLasak Thank you for your recommendation I will look into this and see if I can get it working!!

Comment: Finally, the '1' in 'team1' suggests that the design of your contests table is sub-optimal